# Find the limit as $(x,y,z) \to (0,0,0)$ of a specific function $f(x,y,z)$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

> find $$\lim_{(x,y,z) \to (0,0,0)} \frac{\sin(x^2+y^2+z^2)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}} $$ if exist

$\sin$ is a continuous function so $\lim_{(x,y,z) \to (0,0,0)} \sin(x^2+y^2+z^2)=0$.

$\sqrt{x}$ is not defined for $x<0$ over $\mathbb{R}$ I need to find $x,y,z$ function such that $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}<0$ to prove there is no limit?

Comment: Note that any square of a real number is never negative, so for any $x,y,z$, we know that $x^2 \geq 0$, $y^2 \geq 0$, $z^2 \geq 0$, and $x^2 +y^2 +z^2 \geq 0$. Therefore $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ exists and is non-negative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

$$\frac{\sin(x^2+y^2+z^2)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}=\frac{\sin(x^2+y^2+z^2)}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\cdot\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\;.$$

What do you know about $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\sin x}x$?

Comment: so it is $1*0=0$?

Comment: @gbox: That’s right.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Let $t=x^2+y^2+z^2$ and rewrite our expression as
$$\sqrt{t}\cdot \frac{\sin t}{t}.$$